# Rocketchat does not connect after reboot

Tags: networking, server, snap

I installed and configured rocketchat server snap for URL
[RocketChat](http://leder.no-ip.org:8080)
Now yields 
`502 bad gateway`

And it worked both on desktop app and mobile app.

Now, after doing a shutdown, both are broken. Desktop gives error:
`No valid server found at the URL`

And mobile app says:
`Invalid server version`

Service is up and running with:
`sudo systemctl status snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy`

How do I connect to server successfully, again?

I even cannot configure and access 
[localhost](http://localhost:8080)

I entered channel `--edge` to no avail!

I completely reinstalled rocketchat-server and rocketchat-desktop snaps to no avail!

I know that this could have been asked in ServerFail, too...

`rocketchat-mongo.service` was not running at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove packages via apt and I do not know if I installed them in the first place!

`mongodb-org-server`

`mongodb-org`

`mongodb-org-tools`

in order to get `rocketchat-mongo.service` running and `snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy` responding again.